# Can I draw a gradient linechart with mpAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

[image]

Can I draw a lineChart looks like in the picture? If can, what should I do to change the line colors? Thank you!

what I have draw looks like the picture two,which the line is the same color and there is no yesterday incom.what should I do to change the line into gradient color and only show the last markerView ?

[The picture I have drawn.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4dWN.jpg)

Comment: Show us what you tried?

Comment: have you solved your problem? I got the same request

Answer (score 9):

I've found workaround!
Please check this [tutorial by Lance Gleason.](http://www.polyglotprogramminginc.com/adding-gradients-to-android-graphs-with-mpandroidchart-and-decoview/) It is pretty simple. Here is some code from it:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getView().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setupGradient(chartDaySpeed);
        }
    });
}

private void setupGradient(LineChart mChart) {
    Paint paint = mChart.getRenderer().getPaintRender();
    int height = mChart.getHeight();

    LinearGradient linGrad = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height,
            getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light),
            getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light),
            Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    paint.setShader(linGrad);
}
```

Also here is result:

[Line chart gradient result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5myw.png)

Comment: Instead of `line`, can i fill the area under the graph with gradient?

Comment: Saad Saadi, yes you can.

Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this.getContext(), R.drawable.fade_chart_all);
set1.setFillDrawable(drawable);

Comment: Make sure that `getHeight()` doesn't return 0 by only calling `setupGradient()` after the view has loaded. You can do that by adding an OnGlobalLayoutListener.