# how can I set XAxis values start Draw at second in LineChart MPAdroidChart?

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

[image]

As the picture show, I want draw horizontal values start at second xAxis, I search the MPAndroidChart doc https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki

and I didn't find any solution, I'll be very appreciate if you give me a hand.

Comment: how can we draw gradient line chart?

do you have any ref.

Comment: @RaviMakvana you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748145/can-i-draw-a-gradient-linechart-with-mpandroidchart

Comment: i tried but this one is not working in combined chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about the line value ? or X-Axis value ?

For X-Axis value, you can use a [custom X-Axis value formatter](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-XAxisValueFormatter-interface) like this one :

```
public class MyXAxisValueFormatter implements XAxisValueFormatter {
    @Override
    public String getXValue(String original, int index, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {    
        if (index == 0) return "";
        else return original;
    }
}
```

Then attach your custom formatter to your chart with:

```
chart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatter());
```

---

If you want your LineDataSet start at index 1 and not at index 0, simply add 1 to all Entry indexes in your set.

For instance :
If you have something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> xVals = {"01/04", "02/04", "03/04", ...}  
LineDataSet set1 = {new Entry(yourValue1, 0), new Entry(yourValue2, 1), ...}  
LineDataSet set2 = {new Entry(yourValue1, 1), new Entry(yourValue2, 2), ...}
```

set1 line will start at "01/04"
set2 line will start at "02/04"

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi,00seb, thanks for helping, I mean the X-Axis value.I found that my mpandroidchart version is too old.I pull the newest version and add the code as you say, it works perfect.thank you very much.